# Rails loggerがローテーションしない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby 2.2.2、Rails 4.2.1 にて以下のやり方でログを出力しています。

config/development.rb

```
config.logger = Logger.new('log/my.log', 'daily')
config.log_formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
```

ログ出力コード

```
Rails.logger.info "hogehoge"
```

ログは出力されるのですが、日をまたいでも初めのmy.logに追記されていき、ローテーションされません。開発しながらなので、サーバーは常時起動ではなく、止めたり、起動したりしています。

バッチ的な処理をrailsで書いていて、cronで定期的にURLにアクセスして、処理をして終わるということをしています。

処理は複数スレッドで内部で並列化しています。（常駐スレッドはなし）

テスト環境の別サーバーは常時稼働していますが、同様に初めのファイルに追記されローテーションされません。

ためしに、　dailyをやめて、

```
config.logger = Logger.new('log/my.log', 5, 1 * 1024)
```

のようにサイズ指定にしてみましたが、やはりローテーションされず、かつ今度はログ出力がとても遅くなり、全体的に処理が重くなっているように見えます。

できれば、dailyでログを回したいのですが、どなたか参考情報などありますでしょうか？

Logger自体スレッドセーフだと思ったのですが、マルチスレッド処理が弊害を起こしていますかね？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dailyを指定するとローテートしないのは、Ruby 2.2以降のLoggerのバグだったようです。
修正パッチが登録されていました。

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/f6e77b9d3555c1fbaa8aab1cdc0bd6bde95f62c6

bugs.ruby-lang.org の Bug #12948 と、リビジョン 56815 の変更です。

私の手元の環境(ruby 2.2.1p85, Rails 4.2.1)で同様の現象が起きていましたが、
上記の修正を行った所、dailyでローテートするようになりました。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

> サーバーは常時起動ではなく、止めたり、起動したりしています。

に関しては、サーバの起動時に次回のローテーション時刻を設定しているため、
サーバを止めると無効になると考えます。

Logger.new の際に、
LogDevice.new され、
`@next_rotate_time` に更新日が記憶され、
`write` の度に、`check_shift_log` を行い、
`next_rotate_time` に達していたら、`shift_log_period` で今のファイルをローテーションする、
という動作のようです。

[ruby/logger.rb at trunk · ruby/ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/logger.rb#L589)

```
class LogDevice
  def initialize(log = nil, opt = {})
      # ...
    @dev = open_logfile(log)
    # ...
    @shift_age = opt[:shift_age] || 7
    # ...
    @next_rotate_time = next_rotate_time(Time.now, @shift_age) unless @shift_age.is_a?(Integer)
  end

  def write(message)
    begin
      @mutex.synchronize do
        if @shift_age and @dev.respond_to?(:stat)
          begin
            check_shift_log
    ...

  def check_shift_log
    if @shift_age.is_a?(Integer)
      # Note: always returns false if '0'.
      if @filename && (@shift_age > 0) && (@dev.stat.size > @shift_size)
        lock_shift_log { shift_log_age }
      end
    else
      now = Time.now
      if now >= @next_rotate_time
        @next_rotate_time = next_rotate_time(now, @shift_age)
        lock_shift_log { shift_log_period(previous_period_end(now, @shift_age)) }
      end
    end
  end
```

> テスト環境の別サーバーは常時稼働して

ということですが、例えば Rails.env が異なる、などといったことは無いでしょうか？

## 追記

> daily=２４時間ってことですかね？ 自分はカレンダ情報だと思っていたのですが、２４時間だと、２４時間いないに毎回サーバー落としていたらローテーションされない仕組みですよね？

参照が不足していたようで、スミマセン。
`daily` など文字列で指定した場合は特殊処理をしており、24時間ではなく、日が変わるまでです。

```
 SiD = 24 * 60 * 60

    def next_rotate_time(now, shift_age)
      case shift_age
      when /^daily$/
        t = Time.mktime(now.year, now.month, now.mday) + SiD
```

例えば、2015-07-03 の 9:00 にサーバを起動しても、23:00 に起動しても、
同じく 2015-07-04 には切り替わります。

> Rails.loggerとlogger（コントローラ以外だとRailsをつけないと呼べないってどこかで見ましたが）って、参照してるメソッド（実体）は同じですよね‌​？

`environment.rb` で下記のように設定されていることと思います。
これは、Rails の logger に、Logger クラスを代入しているので、同じものと考えました。

```
config.logger = Logger.new('log/my.log', 'daily')
```

別の logger を使っていれば、そちらの挙動になると考えます。

```
# environment.rb の sample に記載の例
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
上記をみて自分はちょっと勘違いしていたかもしれません。。
daily=２４時間ってことですかね？
自分はカレンダ情報だと思っていたのですが、２４時間だと、２４時間いないに毎回サーバー落としていたらローテーションされない仕組みですよね？

テスト環境もenviroinmentはdevelopemntを使っていますが、プログラム入れ替え時に停止していることもあるので、もうすこしみてみます。

それとついでにお聞きしたいのですが、

Rails.loggerとlogger（コントローラ以外だとRailsをつけないと呼べないってどこかで見ましたが）って、参照してるメソッド（実体）は同じですよね？

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます！

結局なんでローテートしないかわからない感じですが、
あやしいところだと

-Loggerを設定しているのが、environment.rbではなくdevelopment.rb（通常見かけるのは各環境ごとにLoggerの設定をしているコードですが）であること、
-LoggerでなくてActiveLoggerにしてみる？
-常駐ではないが、長いバッチ処理をスレッドで行っていてその中でloggerを参照している（loggerがスレッドセーフでないとか？）

ぐらいかなと思います。
上記試してみるので、またアップデートします！

Comment: 結局、いろいろやってみてダメだったので、ローテーションを自作して解決しました。今回、マルチスレッドなど使っていたので、別のシンプルなアプリを作った時にまた試してみます。ありがとうございました！